# How do foundation classes know what instance to act upon when an instance method is called?

Tags: objective-c, instance-methods

Certain foundation classes such as NSString or NSArray have instance methods that do something with that instance, but never ask for the instance to be given to then. For example:

NSArray *array = @[@"hi"];

Int number = [array count];

The count method knows which array to count without asking for one to be provided. How so you do that?  I'm looking to make a category on NSString with an incrementByOne instance method. I don't want to ask for the string in the method deceleration, I want to know what object I'm performing the action on, just like count knows which array to work on. If anyone can help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example:

```
[array count];
```

you are sending the `count` message to the instance named `array`. The instance the message is sent to is determined by the `array` part of that expression. Inside the method definition, the instance you are acting on is referred to by `self`. In your `incrementByOne` example, the instance method might do something like

```
- (NSInteger)incrementByOne
{
    return [self length] + 1;
}
```

The name `self` will refer to whatever instance that message was sent to.